# Configuration of Redis EC Amazon in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cakephp, redis, cakephp-3.0

I have an elastic Redis cache of AWS and I'm trying to set it in Cakephp unsuccessful ...

My code:

```
        if ($local) {
            Configure::write('debug', 2);
            Configure::write('environmentActive', 'local');
            $configRedis = array(
                'className' => 'Cake\Cache\Engine\RedisEngine',
                'prefix' => 'redis_local_api_tve_',
            );
        } else if ($prod) {
            $configRedis = array(
                'className' => 'Cake\Cache\Engine\RedisEngine',
                'prefix' => 'redis_prod_api_tve_',
                'host' => END POINT OF EC
            );
            Configure::write('debug', 0);
            Configure::write('environmentActive', 'prod');
    }
    Cache::config('Redis', $configRedis);
```

In local REDIS works properly but in prod i have an error of bad configuration...

> Cache engine Cake\Cache\Engine\RedisEngine is not properly configured.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Typically with ElastisCache you have to specify the port along with the Host.  Looking at these docs you probably need to pass the port and Host might need to be server. Http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Cache.Engine.RedisEngine.html

Comment: Yes, i already try that. putting ENDPOINT:PORT in HOST... I try putting SERVER=> ENDPOINT:PORT and HOST => ENDPOINT:PORT... and also without the port, but also the same problem ... @GeorgeMWhitaker

Comment: `$configRedis = array(
                'className' => 'Cake\Cache\Engine\RedisEngine',
                'prefix' => 'redis_prod_api_tve_',
                'server' => END POINT OF EC,
                'port' => "redis_port"
            );` I don't think you are passing it correctly.  Please update your quest with everything you have tried

Comment: I recently resolved this isssue.... Im a silly boy, i never install the php5-redis... so, sudo apt-get install php5-redis and all conflict resolved.. Thanks for all @GeorgeMWhitaker

Answer (score 0):

I recently resolved this isssue. I never install the `php5-redis`. So, `sudo apt-get install php5-redis` and all conflicts are resolved.